# creating spinner in ViewHolder and not in activity class

Tags: android

I'm trying to "hack" the problem of creating a spinner outside activity, by creating a method in the viewHolder class that "Returns" the Spinner and putting the adapter on the activity class, but, I don't know why, it returns "null"

```
 public  @NonNull Spinner returnAsked(int i){
    switch (i){
        case 1:
            return avgDistance;
        case 2:
            return maxDistance;
        case 3:
            return gender;
        default:
            return gender;
    }
}
```

and the code in the activity is:

```
GoogleSignUpViewHolder holder= new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(recyclerView);

holder= new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(recyclerView);
btnAdd= findViewById(R.id.BtnAdd);

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
adapterGender = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.gender_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapterDistance = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.avg_distance_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears

adapterGender.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapterDistance.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
if(holder.returnAsked(1)==null){
    Toast.makeText(this, " CONTEXT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

holder.returnAsked(3).setAdapter(adapterGender);
holder.returnAsked(1).setAdapter(adapterDistance);
holder.returnAsked(2).setAdapter(adapterDistance);
```

This is the adapter code, i think that the problem might be not here.
The XML is a lot of code, i created i think 20 xml files only for the RecykleView

```
public class GoogleSignUpAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GoogleSignUpViewHolder> {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GoogleSignUpViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == 0){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.birthdate_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 1){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gender_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
       else if(viewType == 2){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.avg_distance_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 3){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.avg_speed_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 4){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.picture_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 5){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.address_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 6){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.city_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 7){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.country_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 8){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.height_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 9){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.id_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 10){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.max_distance_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 11){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.max_speed_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 12){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.phone_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == 13){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.weight_item,parent,false);
            return new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(view);
        }




        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GoogleSignUpViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 14;
    }



}
```

Comment: It seems like you trying to "hack" something that does not require hacking. Please explain your layout and what you are trying to achieve. It would make it easier for people to help you..

Comment: ok. so not "hack". sorry.
I'm trying to create a spinner inside a ViewHolder, or create it in the activity but to send the spinner from the viewHolder to the activity, without getting "NULL"

Comment: No worries. I think you should explain your goal or add more code so we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: my goal is to create a spinner inside a scrollView.

Comment: I tried I think almost everything, I tried to send the activity as context to the viewHolder, also as an Activity, but now I'm trying to create it in the activity itself, because it won't work if its not in the activity\

Comment: First, it looks like you are initializing your Adapter twice (new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(recyclerView)). Also, please add your XML & Adapter code.

Comment: Correction: ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

the code is

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ImageButton btnAdd;
    GoogleSignUpAdapter googleSignUpAdapter;
    public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterGender;
    public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterDistance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_sign_up);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.LVG_Add);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        googleSignUpAdapter=new GoogleSignUpAdapter();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(googleSignUpAdapter);
        GoogleSignUpViewHolder holder= new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(recyclerView);
        holder= new GoogleSignUpViewHolder(recyclerView);
        btnAdd= findViewById(R.id.BtnAdd);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        adapterGender = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.gender_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterDistance = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.avg_distance_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapterGender.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterDistance.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        if(holder.returnAsked(1)==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, " CONTEXT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        holder.returnAsked(3).setAdapter(adapterGender);
        holder.returnAsked(1).setAdapter(adapterDistance);
        holder.returnAsked(2).setAdapter(adapterDistance);



    }
}
```

the code of the viewHolder is:

```
public class GoogleSignUpViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    EditText birthdate,picture,address,city,country,height,id,phone,weight,maxSpeed,avgSpeed;

    Activity activity;
    Spinner avgDistance,gender,maxDistance;




    public GoogleSignUpViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        birthdate= itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
        picture=itemView.findViewById(R.id.PictureEditText);
        address=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Address);
        city=itemView.findViewById(R.id.City);
        country= itemView.findViewById(R.id.Country);
        height=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Height);
        id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ID);
        phone=itemView.findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumberEditText);
        weight=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Weight);
        maxSpeed=itemView.findViewById(R.id.MaxSpeedText);
        avgSpeed=itemView.findViewById(R.id.AvgSpeedEditText);
        avgDistance=(Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.AvgDistanceSpiner);
        maxDistance=(Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MaxDistanceSpinner);
        gender=(Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.AvgDistanceSpiner);


    }

    public Spinner returnAsked(int i){
        switch (i){
            case 1:
                if(avgDistance==null){
                    Log.i("TR","BUG");
                }
                return avgDistance;
            case 2:
                return maxDistance;
            case 3:
                return gender;
            default:
                return gender;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You've added the code as an ANSWER to the question. Please remove this answer and add this code to your question (by choosing "Edit" option below the question)